# Raw query changes does not appeared in Entity Object c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've using raw query for update status of a column but after update, changes not appeared in Entity Object:

```
CDIMDEntities oDB = new CDIMDEntities();
SystemYear oSY = oDB.SystemYears.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Year == Year);
if (oSY != null)
{
    string thsQuery = "UPDATE SystemYears SET  " + Column + " = {0} WHERE Id = {1}";
    oDB.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(thsQuery, Status, oSY.Id);
    //After this changes appeared in database 
    // But when again when trying get object ,It's showing old values 
    oSY = oDB.SystemYears.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == oSY.Id);
    this.SystemYearRep.SaveSystemYear(oSY);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because Entity Framework in certain sense "caches" entities. When you make second query

```
oSY = oDB.SystemYears.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == oSY.Id);
```

EF *will* make a database query and it *will* receive updated values from database. But, after doing that it will notice that there is already `SystemYear` with given id attached to the context (that one you received with a first query `oDB.SystemYears.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Year == Year)`). So it will discard new entity and return old one (already attached, with old values) back to you. To force EF refresh entity - use `Reload`:

```
ctx.Entry(oSY).Reload(); // no need to make second query, will be done for you
```

or just use fresh context.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing your raw query on your database, which at the point of initialisation of your `CDIMDEntities()` will not see that change.

```
using(CDIMDEntities oDB = new CDIMDEntities())
{
    SystemYear oSY = oDB.SystemYears.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Year == Year);
    if (oSY != null)
    {
        string thsQuery = "UPDATE SystemYears SET  " + Column + " = {0} WHERE Id = {1}";
        oDB.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(thsQuery, Status, oSY.Id);

        // Your raw query will not affect the SystemYears at this point.
        oSY = oDB.SystemYears.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == oSY.Id);

        // This does nothing at this point.
        this.SystemYearRep.SaveSystemYear(oSY);
    }
}

// New up a another context
using(var CDIMDEntities oDB2 = new CDIMDEntities())
{
   // You will see the changes here
   SystemYear oSY = oDB2.SystemYears.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Year == Year);
}
```

A good practice when new-ing up `DbContext` is by using the `using` keyword, as it helps to dispose the context after usage.